# Linq2Sql: Can I create entities with foreign key relationships without a primary key in both tables?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables in my database that I'm trying to create Linq2Sql entities for. There's more to them than this, but this is essentially what they come down to:

```
Rooms          UserActivity
--------       --------
RoomID         ActivityID 
               RoomID (foreign key on Rooms.RoomID)
```

The `UserActivity` table is essentially just a log for actions a user performs against the Rooms table.

Since the `UserActivity` table is only used for logging actions taken, it didn't make a lot of sense (to me at least) to create a primary key for the table originally, until the Linq2Sql mapper refused to make `UserActivity` a part of the `Room` entity in my Linq entities. When I set up the entities in the Visual Studio designer, I got these 2 warnings:

> - `Warning   1   DBML1062: The Type attribute 'UserActivity' of the Association element 'Room_UserActivity' of the Type element 'Room' does not have a primary key.  No code will be generated for the association.`
> - `Warning   2   DBML1011: The Type element 'UserActivity' contains the Association element 'Room_UserActivity' but does not have a primary key.  No code will be generated for the association.`

These warnings led me to create the `ActivityID` column in my table as displayed above.

What I'd like to know is if there is any way to allow Linq2Sql to create relationships between my entities without having a primary key in both tables. If I don't have the primary key in the `UserActivity` table, the entities can still be created, but the relationships aren't generated.

Is is it possible to do this, or should I try to make sure my tables always have a primary key in them as a general good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any table that stores real data in your app should always have a primary key - most cases, in SQL Server environments, a INT IDENTITY(1,1) will be just fine. You don't have to keep track of those, no bookkeeping necessary etc. It doesn't cost you much, totally easy to do - I don't see any reason why not have a primary key, even on your `UserActivity` table.

```
ALTER TABLE UserActivity
  ADD UserActivityID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
  CONSTRAINT PK_UserActivity PRIMARY KEY
```

and you're done!

The only time I would say no primary key is needed is for things like temporary tables when bulk importing huge amounts of data, or other temporary scenarios.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You need a primary key to create relationships.
It's good practise to always design tables with primary keys, even if you add surrogate (auto increment identity).